# Double quotes being stripped from some HTML tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is a strange issue - one that I've never noticed before.  A verification tag on one of my sites was not being recognised, so I took a closer look at the meta tag and I noticed the double-quotes were missing from the name and content attributes.

Then I spotted a few more tags, some with double quotes missing from both and others where it was missing from just the first attribute.

I thought this was confined to the `<head>` but can see the same occuring in the `<body>`.

I've checked our other sites and their page source looks as I would expect (double quotes surrounding the arguments of each tag), they're also on the same server using the same configuration files.

The site where I am noticing this - skiddmark.com - we've been running now since 2007, and I'm not noticing any functional consequences - it continues to work fine, but I've really no idea why the front-end source code no longer contains these double-quotes.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: My guess is that the quotes in your source are 'smart-quotes' which would likely not be recognized as quotes by the browser.

Comment: There isn't remotely enough information here to help you.  Obviously the problem is something server-side, but you didn't even mention what technologies you are using server-side.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, Quote marks aren't even being sent in the HTML.  This isn't a browser issue.

Comment: Are you sure they are not 'smart-quotes'? (I didn't say it was a browser issue.)

Comment: What's 'smart-quotes'? Please post the information about page generator.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, **Look at the source yourself.**  There are no quotes.  Yes, I'm sure.  I wouldn't have posted otherwise.  Aubin, he probably means left/right quote marks that are available for UTF-8, and other non-ASCII encodings.

Comment: I was initially asking if anyone had observed anything similar, because as I said, the other sites on our server, configured in exactly the same way, are not displaying the same issue when viewed at page source.  The server is a Centos 5.5, Apache 5.3 server running a variety of applications (from Python Django to Wordpress PHP).  The site I refer to is based on a Wordpress platform.

Comment: @Aubin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_electronic_documents

Comment: @Brad How can I look at the source without it passing through the server and then a browser?

Comment: @CitizenS, Again, there is absolutely no way to help you if you don't provide useful information.  Questions like "has anyone seen this" are not appropriate for StackOverflow, because they are effectively unanswerable.  Please see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @KevinBoucher, Look at the HTML returned from the server.  That's the point... the issue is not client-side.

Comment: @Brad There was enough information to give me an idea what the issue is. He sees quotes in the source (locally) but not when the page is rendered in the browser. Again, I'm still guessing the issue is smart-quotes.

Comment: @Brad -- I never said it was a browser-issue, nor a client-side issue. Do you even know what I'm talking about?

Comment: @Brad, I am well aware of how to ask questions on StackOverflow.  It's a valid opening gambit to say, this behavior seems unusual and before I pick it apart completely has anyone ever noticed anything similar.  For instance I went through all of the tags and made sure there was a forward slash at the end - just in case this was causing an issue with my DOCTYPE.  If nothing rings a bell, then fine, that's precisely why I was asking..

Comment: What browser are you viewing the source in if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @War10ck I am viewing it on Firebox Beta 17.0

Comment: @CitizenS Got ya. The reason I'm asking is I've noticed the same behavior on a site of my own when I view it in Google Chrome. If I have my DOCTYPE set as xhtml then the quotes are left in the source. However, when I changed all of my pages to the new HTML5 DOCTYPE as I saw on your page, the quotes on many of my html attributes went away.

Comment: +1 to negate Brad's downvote.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher, in answer to your question, the quotes in the original PHP file are just quotes - standard keyboard quotes - it doesn't matter whether they are entered via Dreamweaver or directly in SSH, they're standard quotes which are not all showing that way in the browser source.  I've scanned through for any malware or other such nasties and the code is clean.

Comment: @CitizenS Roger that. Too bad, that's all I could come up with. War10ck's comment looks interesting though. Good luck.

Comment: @War10ck - thanks, that's why I was wondering if it was caused by the DOCTYPE.  Unfortunately I've not noticed it before today, so don't know how long it's been this way - although I would have expected to have noticed it before now.  I'd also be surprised if it were a server issue, not just becuase my other sites are unaffected, but also because I've no idea how the server config would have any bearing on the such a specific pattern of formatting at the browser end.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher - thanks Kevin.

Comment: @CitizenS Yeah not to rain on anyone's parade but that really doesn't sound like a server side issue. It sounds more like a rendering issue or how the browser is treating the file with the given DOCTYPE. Not sure. I'm with you though, I would expect all of your sites to have a similar behavior if it were something to do with the server config file. Hope you get it fixed buddy. Good luck.

Comment: **This is not a client-side issue.**  Don't believe me?  Prove it to yourself with cURL.  `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" http://skiddmark.com`  If you don't trust your console, dump it to a file and open a hex editor.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, Yes, I do know what I am talking about.  Your very first comment, "My guess is that the quotes in your source are 'smart-quotes' which would likely not be recognized as quotes by the browser", seems to imply that you thought the problem was client side.  Furthermore, what makes you think I was the one that downvoted this question?  I am trying to help CitizenS here by explaining that this can't possibly be a client-side issue, since those quotes never make it to the client.  The problem **must** be server-side, and he hasn't given sufficient information to help the root cause.

Comment: @Brad Dude, you need to chill out. I didn't ask if you knew 'what you were talking about'. I asked if you knew 'what _I_ was talking about'. And you still don't seem to. To be clear my suggestion was a problem with the source code. Not the browser, not any other client-side considerations. You've spent more time arguing with other people than helping CitizenS. Good day, sir.

Comment: @Brad What made me think you downvoted the question was your general attitude. Forgive me if my assumption was incorrect.

Comment: @Brad - I'm sure I've asked this question already, but just in case it's been overlooked in the subsequent comments, 'do you have any suggestions for where to begin problem solving this symptom?'  The reason why I ask is because I've never come across (or heard) of such an occurance and I can confirm that it doesn't affect every site on this server.  I don't need a solution - just 'any' suggestions for a reasonable starting point, assuming the cause originates server side (which I'm happy to explore).

Comment: @CitizenS, By "server side" I don't necessarily mean the server software itself.  I am referring to anything that runs on the server, including your web application.  Start by showing us a relevant snippet of your WordPress template, and any special code you have building the final output.

Comment: @Brad - listen thanks for your help, but that's precisely what I don't want to do - I spend enough time hardening my sites and concealing their constitution without posting snippets of my code.  My original question was "Has anyone experienced something similar", and apart from War10ck, the answer seems to be 'No'.  I will discover the reason, I just didn't see any point in reinventing the wheel if others had experienced something similar.

Comment: @CitizenS, If you believe your site will be compromised by posting a snippet of template code, so be it.  I cannot provide any other advice to you, as there is not enough information to narrow down the problem.  Look at your templates, look at any filtering and processing you may be doing elsewhere.  The problem has to be server-side.  Made any WordPress upgrades lately?  Also, narrow down the reproducible test case.  If I remember from skimming earlier, it seemed that not all of your HTML had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in the answer to my question, the cause of my missing quotation marks was due to Google's modPagespeed which I've been running for several years now, but which I upgraded to the latest development version last month.

I will get in touch with the modPagespeed team and report it as a bug and see if we can find a solution.

Thanks for everybody's contribution and comments - as I said, I wasn't looking for 'advice' or a ready-made 'solution', just a discussion which would help free up my imagination and help me think laterally..

Comment: It sounds like a feature, not a bug. modPagespeed (presumably) attempts to reduce the file size of the page so it downloads faster. Removing optional quote characters would contribute to that.

Comment: @Quentin you may be right, although it only strips 'some' of the double quotes, not all.  Likewise it screws up the parsing of validation tags, which is how I discovered it in the first place.  If it's a feature, then it's not a particularly worthwhile one.

Comment: Looking at the source of your page suggests it removes the quotes from all attributes with values that contain no characters that would require quoting (such as spaces). What are "validation tags"?

Comment: The usual ones such as google webmaster tools, bing, alexa traffic monitoring and a new malware checker - if I set 'modPagespeed Off' then the full quotes are rendered.